# Test if an exception was catched in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

How do I test if an exception was catched in [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)?

The expectation is true if I remove the `try...catch` statement but I'm not interested on that.

**Spec**

```
import { foo } from './src';

describe('app', () => {
  it('should match if an exception was catched', () => {
    expect(() => foo()).toThrow();
  });
});
```

**Source**

```
function foo() {
  try {
    throw new Error();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

export { foo };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we could spyOn `console.log` to check this output, and test whether this `Error` is catched or not.

```
// Test
spyOn(console, 'log');
foo();
expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Error());
```